# In Mercurial, move old file to location, move new files into old file location with same names

Tags: merge, mercurial, branch, rename

This should be simple, but something isn't quite right. Here is my scenario and then I'll give a brief overview of the commands I'm using. It helps to know that we have 3 specific dev areas, Live, Staging, and of course our own local dev areas.

I developed a new "beta" area of my site which has gone live and had appropriate testing. Now I'm ready to move it from a beta directory, to where it really should be and move out the old. When I do it locally, it seems fine, but when I try to merge my local branch into the staging branch, it doesn't seem to map the files correctly, and gives me a bunch of those `use (c)hanged version, (d)elete, or leave (u)nresolved?` prompts. The problem comes when my old directory has files that are named the same as the beta directory (like index.php for instance). Here's a quick example of what I mean:

```
currentDir/index.php
currentDir/update.php
currentDir/another_file.php

currentDir-beta/index.php
currentDir-beta/update.php
currentDir-beta/a_new_file.php
currentDir-beta/another_new_file.php
```

This is my process.

```
# creates a new branch from the live branch
hg branch new-branch-name

# move the current directory somewhere else
hg mv currentDir/* currentDir-old/

# commit...
hg com -m "moved current to -old"

# everything is fine up to this point

# move the beta directory to where the old one was
hg mv currentDir-beta/* currentDir/

# when I run hg st, it only shows that files are being removed from the -beta directory and added to the new/old directory

# commit
hg com -m "moved -beta to currentDir"

# when this commits is when the problems start happening. 
# At this point when I run this next command, it shows that
# currentDir/index.php and other common files are now "modified" instead of "added"
hg st --rev "max(ancestors('new-branch-name') and branch(live)):'new-branch-name'"

# then try to merge to staging
hg up staging
hg merge new-branch-name

# errors happen with "common" file names like index.php. It treats them as though they were only modified instead of added.
```

Even if I ignored the above "modified" quirk, when I go to merge this new branch into the staging branch with other changes programmers have done, it complains that "local has this which remote deleted". I really wouldn't care with most of this as I could just throw this live and then any new branches would have this change. The thing I do care about is that any work done in the currentDir-beta folder on those "common" files from other programmers will no longer map to the new location. I can copy/paste the code and commit it, but it basically means that those branches are hosed as it pertains to keeping the changes other programmers did on those common files. To give you an example of what I mean, when I merge and type `hg st` it might look something like this.

```
M currentDir/index.php
M currentDir/update.php
M currentDir/a_new_file.php # why is this M? It should be A right?
M currentDir/another_new_file.php # why is this M? It should be A right?
M currentDir-old/another_file.php # why is this M? It should be A right?
R currentDir/another_file.php
R currentDir-beta/index.php
R currentDir-beta/update.php
R currentDir-beta/a_new_file.php
R currentDir-beta/another_new_file.php
```

Any suggestions on how to get around this? My goal is to make it so existing code changes that took place in currentDir-beta are "forwarded" to currentDir/ in the staging environment. All the other "not common" file changes are mapped, just not these common files.

### UPDATE

Forgot to mention, I'm using Mercurial 3.9 on macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know

- Your version of Mercurial
- OS

but on my Win-box with Mercurial-3.9.1 my impressions (and results) differ

Clean initial state (folders shortened due to lazyness)

```
>hg st -A
C Current-beta\a_new_file.php
C Current-beta\another_new_file.php
C Current-beta\index.php
C Current-beta\update.php
C Current\another_file.php
C Current\index.php
C Current\update.php
```

First rename

```
>hg mv Current Current-Backup
moving Current\another_file.php to Current-Backup\another_file.php
moving Current\index.php to Current-Backup\index.php
moving Current\update.php to Current-Backup\update.php
```

...commit details skipped...

Second rename

```
>hg mv Current-beta Current
moving Current-beta\a_new_file.php to Current\a_new_file.php
moving Current-beta\another_new_file.php to Current\another_new_file.php
moving Current-beta\index.php to Current\index.php
moving Current-beta\update.php to Current\update.php
```

and working directory after it (as expected)

```
>hg st
A Current\a_new_file.php
A Current\another_new_file.php
A Current\index.php
A Current\update.php
R Current-beta\a_new_file.php
R Current-beta\another_new_file.php
R Current-beta\index.php
R Current-beta\update.php
```

...commit details skipped...

If you want to see how it was recorded by Mercurial: I used such slightly puzzling at first glance log for better interpreting of output

```
hg log -T "{rev}:{node|short}\n{if(file_adds,'\tAdded: {join(file_adds,', ')}\n')}{if(file_copies,'\tCopied: {join(file_copies,', ')}\n')}{if(file_dels,'\tDeleted: {join(file_dels,', ')}\n')}{if(file_mods,'\tModified: {join(file_mods,', ')}\n')}\n"
```

and here it's result

```
2:98955fcb7e71
        Added: Current/a_new_file.php, Current/another_new_file.php, Current/index.php, Current/update.php
        Copied: Current/a_new_file.php (Current-beta/a_new_file.php), Current/another_new_file.php (Current-beta/another_new_file.php), Current/index.php (Current-beta/index.php), Current/update.php (Current-beta/update.php)
        Deleted: Current-beta/a_new_file.php, Current-beta/another_new_file.php, Current-beta/index.php, Current-beta/update.php

1:61068c6ba8a7
        Added: Current-Backup/another_file.php, Current-Backup/index.php, Current-Backup/update.php
        Copied: Current-Backup/another_file.php (Current/another_file.php), Current-Backup/index.php (Current/index.php), Current-Backup/update.php (Current/update.php)
        Deleted: Current/another_file.php, Current/index.php, Current/update.php


0:454486bc43e5
        Added: Current-beta/a_new_file.php, Current-beta/another_new_file.php, Current-beta/index.php, Current-beta/update.php, Current/another_file.php, Current/index.php, Current/update.php
```

As you can see - no edits ("Modified") at all (and here log /per changeset/ is more correct than **aggregated** status)

PS: I couldn't see on the fly purpose of your revset in `hg st` and necessity of branching+merging

PPS: OK, I saw

```
>hg st --rev "0:"
M Current\index.php
M Current\update.php
A Current-Backup\another_file.php
A Current-Backup\index.php
A Current-Backup\update.php
A Current\a_new_file.php
A Current\another_new_file.php
R Current-beta\a_new_file.php
R Current-beta\another_new_file.php
R Current-beta\index.php
R Current-beta\update.php
R Current\another_file.php
```

**Aggregated results** in considering **only the boundary** conditions is (correctly, technically speaking) *modified* files for files 1) in the same location 2) with the same name 3) and with changed content

Comment: Thank you for the fabulous explanation. So question though in regards do your PS and PPS, when I merge the two branches, the changes that exist on the Current-beta/index.php file on staging, do not get merged properly in my local repo to Current/index.php. All the changes that exist currently in staging on that index file, never make it over to the "renamed" index file. That's what my concern is. From what it sounds like, I should just suck it up and deal with it and it should work.

Comment: It makes me wonder, when that happens should I run `hg mv -A Current-beta/index.php Current/index.php` ?

Comment: @ImmortalFirefly - sorry, can't catch the idea `Current-beta/index.php` **IS** `Current/index.php` after 2-nd `hg mv`. *Why* do you want to perform some additional action?! `mv -A` is at least useless - move already happened and stored (correctly) !!!!

Comment: @ImmortalFirefly - maybe `hg log -f  Current/index.php` will shed some light for you?

Comment: When I run `hg log -f Current/index.php` before the merge, it shows all the changes, and looks the way I would hope. Where I get confused is I run the command to merge it with the staging branch, it has all those merging issues, and then I run `hg log -f Current/index.php` (even before I commit the merge) and now `hg log` is missing all the expected commits that I just saw on the same file a few seconds before. Is this the part that you were talking about with your PSS above? That those commits will magically show up after I commit the merge?

Comment: @ImmortalFirefly - rename history (for -f) is part of commit metadata, thus - yes, you have to commit mergeset in order to see former file history in log for new file

Comment: I just completed the merge and pushed it to staging. It seems ok for now and it picked up the changes like i was hoping. Maybe I was being too skiddish :)

Comment: As a follow up for anyone who reads this..... is still didn't work perfectly. We ended up just throwing this to our live code as quick as we could. Merges to staging were a bit awkward with sometimes difficult code conflicts. After we pushed it to live, our new branches are great.